# How to not pull string down while pressing it

Tags: guitar, practice

I have bought my first electric guitar but I have a small problem. When I press strings, I noticed that I pull them a little bit down, like I intend to bend it a little. What does it called and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is common for beginners, especially on the low strings. There is not a specific name for it. My observation after teaching many beginners is that people sometimes tend to think of pressing down a string as being a squeezing motion. When you squeeze something your fingers bend inwards, which on a guitar neck translates into pressing and pulling down at the same time.

In order to avoid this you want to think of your fingers as going directly into the fingerboard, even with a slightly upward motion. kind of like extending your fingers towards the neck instead of curving them more as you press. You want to keep your fingers a bit more straight as you press as opposed to curving them

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very good that you are noticing this as a beginner and that it bothers you. It is common issue and it takes some targeted practice to limit this.

But first of all I'd start from looking at the setup and string gauge in your guitar. We're all different and some have lighter touch others have heavier grip so it is worth experimenting a bit with string action and gauge to suit your attitude and touch.

Then even practicing regular scales across the neck but with paying attention to press string as light as possible and without any lateral shift/bend will improve the situation in time. It is also important to look at the same issue when playing chords, especially harder one where there is a tendency to grip harder and practice this with the focus on stabilizing hand position and using less force.